# I started encrypting my hard drive and now I have lost free space?

Tags: windows-7

I have a 500 GB hard drive which has 160 GB free space. I started encrypting it and suddenly it showed I had only 6 GB left? What can I do to get my memory back? Why did this happening? I stopped encrypting it, but there is no change.

Answer (score 5):

BitLocker does this to encrypt the free space. The 6GB is to allow you to continue working during the encryption process. You get the space back once the encryption process has ended.

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee449438.aspx#BKMK_FreeSpace

Answer (score -3):

Try a **system restore**. If you have a restore point otherwise use an application like ccleaner to clean up space that is unwanted.

Comment: What encryption system are you using? If you use an encryption system that reserves a block in advance, such as TrueCrypt, then you've created a 154 GB "folder" or virtual drive for encryption, though that "folder" may contain no files yet.

Comment: This just seems like a wild guess solution. It also isn't required to solve the author's problem.  The author simply needs to finish encrypting their drive.